# Computing projective dimension over hereditary rings (modules).

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I want to prove this example from Rotman's which I have not found proved in literature yet and Im curious about. Let $_{R}M$ be a left module over a left herditary ring $R$, then $p.d(_{R}M) \leq 1$,i.e, projective dimension of $_{R} M$ is less than or equal to one.

So here we go writing all we need (I guess), let $R$ be a ring, we say that $R$ is a **left hereditary ring** if every left ideal $I$ of $R$ is projective as a left module over $R$. According to Rotman´s Homological Algebra we have that the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $R$ is left hereditary ring,

(ii) Submodules of projective left $R$ modules are projective,

(iii) Quotients of injective left $R$ modules are injective.

To prove $p.d(_{R}M)\leq 1$ Rotman suggest using (ii) of the last list of equivalences. So proving this means that for every projective resolution

$$...\rightarrow P_{2} \rightarrow P_{1} \rightarrow P_{0} \rightarrow _{R} M \rightarrow 0 ,$$

$P_{i}=0$ for every $i \geq 1$. But first of all, I need to show I always have $P_{0}$  projective. But I dont have an idea about how to  construct this  $P_{0}$ and the respective morphism. Any help proving this example will be useful.

Comment: I always thought that the projective dimension of any module over a hereditary ring was $\le 1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are totally right! My fault, let me edit the question properly,thanks! @AnginaSeng

Comment: All the $P_i$ are projective by definition, in any projective resolution...  you don't need to show $P_0$ is projective at all. You need to find a reason that you only need $1$ or $2$ nonzero $P$'s

Comment: We can proceed supposing $P_{2} \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$? @rschwieb Still not get the idea of this one

Comment: What happens if you consider the kernel of the map $P_{0}\to M$?

Comment: Well, this kernel will be a submodule of $P_{0}$, then it would be a projective submodule ...@Zeek

Comment: So you have an exact sequence $0\to K \to P_{0}\to M\to 0$ with $K$ projective. This tells you the projective dimension of $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zeek! This was the first proof I do which involves calculating a projective dimension, so I was thinking about it in a more complex way that made me scary. So we can take larger projective resolutions  of $M$ but as this is the shorter one, we have that $p.d(M) \leq 1$?. We dont have to guarantee $P_{0}$ exist?

Comment: That's right, because the projective dimension is the minimal length of the resolution. Projective resolutions always exist (for modules over rings) because there's always a surjection $P\to M$ with $P$ projective.